# How to count number of logins in C language

Tags: arrays, c, file, counter, increment

Well I'm making a program that initially asks to login or register.

I need to make a counter for each time the program is accessed (after the login).

[C language using the array of functions and file Login Register](https://www.programmersought.com/article/24082299748/)

The method to log in and register follows the one up.

My thing is due to the lifetime of the var, because I know the moment the program ends the var just restarts.

So far I tried many ways. By macros but once again soon as the program ends it restarts.
I'm starting now to make one saving in files.

I started just now so the function is very simple, but since I only have more 2 hours to deliver the work so I hope you guys help me.

Simple function:

[image]

Comment: Modify the `stuct` `User` and add `size_t logins;` Modify `registerUser()` to initialize `logins = 0;` if the user is not found. Modify `writeToFile(User u)` to write `logins` to the file. That is the cleanest way to approach it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the definition of `fp` you should call the function `fopen`. From the [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) of `fopen`:

> w+
> Open for reading and writing. The file is created if it
> does not exist, otherwise it is truncated.  The stream is
> positioned at the beginning of the file.

The file gets truncated and you need to read it before you open it for writing.

```
fp = fopen("contador.txt", "r");
if (!fp) {
   perror("fopen");
   return -1;
}
fscanf(fp, "%d", &contador);
fclose(fp);
fp = fopen("contador.txt", "w");
```

You can use [fscanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fscanf) for parsing the file and storing the value into your variable.